# What does this sentence/idiom/phrase mean?

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

I saw a sentence in a book:

> When George heard that the meal was on the house, he went to thank the restaurant owner for the free food.

The sentence does not make sense to me. I tried Google translating to other languages, but did not work as well.

Is there a specific idiom or phrase that I'm not familiar with?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Which part of the sentence is causing you a problem?

Comment: @KillingTime  The phrase "the meal was on the house"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On the house" means that you are given something for free, that you would usually pay for.

> (of a drink or meal in a bar or restaurant) at the management's expense; free.

[Lexico](https://lexico.com/definition/on-the-house)

You can think of the sentence like this:

> When George heard that the meal was <strike>on the house</strike> *given to him for free by the owner*, he went to thank the restaurant owner for the free food.